# Planned contrasts to test a priori hypotheses

Tags: anova, lsmeans, planned-comparisons-test

I am planning a study with three between conditions. Let's say *"Experimental group"* vs. *"Control group"* vs. *"Placebo group"*. And I have a numeric outcome *"DV"* from 1 to 10.

My prediction is that that *"DV"* will be higher in *"Experimental group"* compared to each of the other two groups. And I predict that there will be no difference between the other two groups (*Control* and *Placebo*).

I want to use **planned contrasts** to test this in **R**. But I'm not sure about the appropriate method. I have read that this provides more statistical power with a priori hypotheses, than conducting the anova, and then looking at pairwise comparisons post-hoc with bonferonni corrections.

I found 2 methods online for planned contrasts, and I would like to know which one to choose.

Method 1:

Create contrast weights in the data set (with number of contrasts = k-1, and sum of contrasts =0, and sum of their products = 0)

```
data$C1 <- 2*(data$group == "experimental") + -1*(data$group =="control") + -1*(data$group=="placebo")

data$C2 <- 0*(data$group == "experimental") + 1*(data$group =="control") + -1*(data$group=="placebo")
```

and then use a linear model to test both contrasts at the same time:

```
model <- lm(DV ~ C1 + C2, data=data)
summary(model)
```

and for my hypotheses to be true C1 must be significant, but C2 must not.

Method 2:

```
library(emmeans)

model <- lm (DV ~ factor(group), data=data)

emmeans(model, specs = pairwise ~ group)
```

and then look at the pairwise comparisons.

I'm unsure as to whether both cases are equivalent. Also, I feel like in both cases I end up looking at multiple p-values anyway. With the first method, I look at the p-value for C1 AND for C2. And with the second method, I look at the significance of each pairwise contrasts...

I'm unclear about the best approach to test my hypothesis.

I apologize if this has been answered before in another post, I must have missed it. If this is the case, please refer me to that post.

Thank you in advance!